# Worker starts, then shuts down. No errors

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a problem with the launch of celery tasks. When you run the following command locally `celery -A codebase worker --loglevel=debug --beat` I get the following response

```
/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:30: DeprecationWarning: twisted.internet.interfaces.IStreamClientEndpointStringParser was deprecated in Twisted 14.0.0: This interface has been superseded by IStreamClientEndpointStringParserWithReactor.
      from twisted.internet.interfaces import (

    DEBUG 2014-09-05 14:58:02,450 base 25908 139809439647552 Configuring Raven for host: http://69a23c7e80df4276822e771e1dec86e4:26eedecf43e34073b987b81151fd1ff9@localhost:9000:/10
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,723: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,726: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,727: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Beat, Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoreloader, StateDB, Autoscaler, Consumer}
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,739: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,740: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,757: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Agent, Events, Mingle, Gossip, Heart, Tasks, Control, event loop}

     -------------- celery@krassi-Satellite-L505 v3.1.13 (Cipater)
    ---- **** ----- 
    --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-35-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
    -- * - **** --- 
    - ** ---------- [config]
    - ** ---------- .> app:         codebase:0x7f27e88a4f90
    - ** ---------- .> transport:   django://localhost//
    - ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
    - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
    -- ******* ---- 
    --- ***** ----- [queues]
     -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


    [tasks]
      . celery.backend_cleanup
      . celery.chain
      . celery.chord
      . celery.chord_unlock
      . celery.chunks
      . celery.group
      . celery.map
      . celery.starmap
      . geoloc.tasks.get_real_geolocation
      . sofiatraffic_crawler.tasks.crawl_sofitraffic
      . sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_stop
      . sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_transport

    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,767: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Beat
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,771: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,772: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,777: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,780: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: intial read
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,781: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,806: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,806: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,818: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to django://localhost//
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,819: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,819: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,829: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,829: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,832: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,832: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,833: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,865: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,866: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,871: DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:
    <ModelEntry: scrap-sofitraffic-every-day sofiatraffic_crawler.tasks.crawl_sofitraffic(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: delete-stop-every-day sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_stop(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: delete-transport-every-day sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_transport(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: get-real-location-every-day geoloc.tasks.get_real_geolocation(*[], **{}) {4}>
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,873: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,873: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
    [2014-09-05 14:58:02,874: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@krassi-Satellite-L505 ready.
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,540: INFO/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,541: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,541: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,557: DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:
    <ModelEntry: scrap-sofitraffic-every-day sofiatraffic_crawler.tasks.crawl_sofitraffic(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: delete-stop-every-day sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_stop(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: delete-transport-every-day sofiatraffic_data.tasks.delete_transport(*[], **{}) {4}>
    <ModelEntry: get-real-location-every-day geoloc.tasks.get_real_geolocation(*[], **{}) {4}>
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,558: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
    [2014-09-05 14:58:03,573: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 4.99 seconds.
```

Everything is OK, the process continues and go.
Then transfer to the server, run it with the same command and I get the following response:

```
/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:30: DeprecationWarning: twisted.internet.interfaces.IStreamClientEndpointStringParser was deprecated in Twisted 14.0.0: This interface has been superseded by IStreamClientEndpointStringParserWithReactor.
  from twisted.internet.interfaces import (

DEBUG 2014-09-05 15:03:14,511 base 7100 140161706530560 Configuring Raven for host: http://69a23c7e80df4276822e771e1dec86e4:26eedecf43e34073b987b81151fd1ff9@localhost:9000:/10
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,694: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,696: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,696: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Beat, Timer, Hub, Queues (intra), Pool, Autoreloader, Autoscaler, StateDB, Consumer}
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,723: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,723: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,731: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Agent, Heart, event loop}

 -------------- celery@dexter.mtrdev.com v3.1.13 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.2.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         codebase:0x138e5d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   django://localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap

[2014-09-05 15:03:14,735: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Beat
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,737: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,737: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,739: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,751: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,751: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,751: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,756: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to django://localhost//
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,756: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,756: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,758: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: intial read
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,758: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,760: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,760: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,763: DEBUG/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,766: DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:

[2014-09-05 15:03:14,772: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Beat...
[2014-09-05 15:03:14,772: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Pool...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,046: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,052: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 4.99 seconds.
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,549: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Consumer...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,549: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Consumer...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,550: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Pool...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,778: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Beat...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,779: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Shutting down...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,779: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Heart...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,779: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,779: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Control...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,779: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Tasks...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,780: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,780: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Events...
[2014-09-05 15:03:15,780: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Connection...
```

And once you start worker immediately stops without errors without anything. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Do you any other workers on server? You are using `--beat` while starting a worker. There should be only one instance of it.

Comment: There are `gunicorn: worker`, `nginx: worker` who takes care of the Sentry.

Comment: Do you different config in local sys & server? Looks like 1st worker is processing more tasks than 2nd worker.

Comment: the problem turned out to be in the Kombu 3.0.22. There is a problem in this version.

Comment: Thanks for this! I got hit by this problem yesterday too. Kombu 3.0.21 does the job!

Comment: please turn your comment into an answer then?

Comment: @JörnHees I wrote my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be in the Kombu 3.0.22. There is a problem in this version.